# Assigning a watched array multiple values but read the change once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What would be the method to assign an array, which is watched by, so change to an array would propagate only once?

```
$scope.data = [field1:'1',field2:'2',field3:'3'];

scope.$watch('data', function (newVal) { /*...*/ }, true);

$scope.data['field1'] = '3';
$scope.data['field2'] = '2';
$scope.data['field3'] = '1';
```

This would trigger watch 3 times, is it possible make an assignment as a collection of values?

I thought maybe its possible to do with a copy of 'data' and assign to it after I modify a copy?

```
var copyofdata = $scope.data;
copyofdata['field1'] = '3';
copyofdata['field2'] = '2';
copyofdata['field3'] = '1';
$scope.data = copyofdata;
```

But maybe there is more elegant solution not involving temp copy?

Answer (score 1):

> From http://plnkr.co/edit/xJrpDNPZjm7bPxgNLpM4?p=preview by
>   @petrAveryanov in answer above, there is no problem in watching an
>   array, but still i would like to give a bit of insight on is there a
>   solution to your question(would it be possible to change the elements
>   inside an array, and mimic like there is only one change on the array)

what you are doing, 1. make a copy of data, 2. changing it, and 3. then assigning it to original data, is the most elegant solution to your problem, so far, till the current versions of angular.

even if angular doesnt provide this kind of functionality to watch , we would think of giving a try to combine,

```
$scope.data['field1'] = '3';
$scope.data['field2'] = '2';
$scope.data['field3'] = '1';
```

But that's not currently possible in javascript(as of today) , not even in next release of javascript i.e. ecma-script-6.

So it would be better to stick with your approach.

Comment: thanks for your insight, maybe it is only possible to go with temporary copy...

Answer (score 1):

http://plnkr.co/edit/xJrpDNPZjm7bPxgNLpM4?p=preview

You are wrong, your code triggers `$watch` 1 time. (2 times including initial one).

Comment: you are right, something I have overlooked, deleting question...

Comment: dont delete the question, let it be for future readers